# Adding objects from derived classes

Tags: c++, class, derived

I am stuck on using the operator + between derived classes. This is my first time working with derived classes too, so any tips would be much appreciated.

Anyway, the code:

```
// Base class
class atom { ... }
// Not quite sure what the base class needs

//derived class
class hydrogen: public atom {
private:
    double bonds_ = 1;
public:
//other code
//method that returns string of bonds_
//method that adds bonds_
}

//derived class
class carbon: public atom {
private:
    double bonds_ = 4;
public:
//other code
//method that returns a string of bonds_
//method that adds bonds_
}

int main(){
hydrogen h;
carbon c;

h = c + h;
// adding a derived class with another

std::cout << h.get_bond_string() << std::endl;
//should be 5 

return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out a way to add two derived class objects together. Any ideas?

I've tried adding an operator function in the derived class, like:

```
//in the carbon derived class,

hydrogen carbon::operator+(hydrogen h){
    carbon c; //creates a default carbon c
    h.add_bonds(c, 1);

//adds the bonds together; first parameter is the element,
//second parameter is quantity of the element


return h;
};
```

Note: I am confident my methods for adding bonds or returning a string is functioning. I just can't figure out how to add two derived classes.

Comment: You want to define the `_bonds` field and the `+` operator on your base class, that way you can "add" any 2 classes deriving from `atom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it could use some *templates*.

First the basic `atom` class

```
class atom
{
private:
    size_t bonds_;

public:
    explicit atom(size_t const bonds)
        : bonds_{bonds}
    {}

    // Other functions...
    // For example the `add_bonds` function
};
```

Then the child classes

```
struct hydrogen : public atom
{
    hydrogen()
        : atom{1}
    {}
};

struct carbon : public atom
{
    carbon()
        : atom{4}
    {}
};
```

And finally the templated `operator+` function

```
template<typename A, typename B>
B operator+(A a, B b)
{
    // TODO: b.add_bonds(1, a);
    return b;
}
```

This will allow you to write

```
h = c + h;
```

or

```
c = h + c;
```

or more generally

```
auto new_atom = h + c;  // or c + h
```

Important disclaimer: The `operator+` function as provided may brake some basic chemistry rules. It was to long since I knew anything about chemistry. :)